# I need a different tab group activity having parent child concept

Tags: android, tabs

I want to use tab group activity and I do not want to use this code

```
    this.tabHost = getTabHost();

    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch the first Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, LoginTab.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for the first tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Login").setIndicator("Login",
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.login)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

I actually want to use parent child concept in this, so please help me....